# MongoDB move ObjectId from one field to another

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

***Problem***

I have an ObjectId saved in a field -incomingFriendRequests- and I want to move it to another field -friends-.

Is there a better way to do this than to remove it from receivedFriendRequests and then do an findOneAndUpdate to add it to friends? I feel like this can be accomplished with one database call instead of two.

***Code***

Mongoose Model:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
  friends: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', require: false
  }],
  incomingFriendRequests:[{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', require: false
  }],
  online: {type: Boolean, require: true}
});
```

Comment: Do you want to run this once for all documents or only for one specific ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in a single query you need to first perform $pull on the incomingFriendRequests field for remove selected objectId and then you need to perform another update query on friends for add selected objectId. also, you can use $addToSet to preventing duplication id. if you use $push for add in that case duplicate objectId also store.

Query :-

1) Remove :- db.getCollection('testdata').update({id:ObjectId('5cc3fa66a04275096417f9ca')},{"$pull":{"incomingFriendRequests":"5cc3fa66a04275096417f9da"}}});

2) add :- 
db.getCollection('testdata').update({id:ObjectId('5cc3fa66a04275096417f9ca')},{"$addToSet":{"friends":"5cc3fa66a04275096417f9da"}});  // also you can use $push

Answer (score 0):

Moving values from one field to another would definitely need n + 1 calls to do the transformation. This can be achieved using

```
find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
  // your doc update
  doc.save();
});
```

Or you can even perform a bulkwrite.

In case if your goal is to delete the column incomingFriendRequests, you can probably rename the column to friends instead copying all the data.

```
update({}, { $rename: {incomingFriendRequests: friends }});
```